# sql - order of case statements

Tags: sql

have the following code:

```
select a,b,c,d
case when a > 5 or a < 2 then null end as a
case when a is null then null when a = 0 then b else b/a end as e
from table
```

effectively I want to exclude every single row where a > 5 or a < 2, then perform calculations on that only. The above code fails in the second case as it does not consider the first case when

Comment: That's a case expression, not statement.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't clear; can't use use the `WHERE` clause to exclude the items you don't want to compute?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: All expressions within a single `select` clause are evaluated *as if* they're all being evaluated in parallel. You can't have one expression depend on the result of a different expression, even if you give it the same name as an existing column.

Comment: @user33484,Specify sample data and expected output.

Comment: I wouldn't alias a as a and then use a in a second case (it's difficult to maintain and understand use a different alias unless you really mean the column a in the second case and even then, I'd use a different alias on the first case..  mySQL may support this but pretty confident SQLserver, Oracle, DB2 wouldn't for the reason @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> effectively I want to exclude every single row where a > 5 or a < 2,
>   then perform calculations on that only.

You don't filter rows with `case`.  You filter rows with `where`:

```
select a, b, c, d,
       (case when a = 0 then b else b/a end) as e
from table
where a >= 2 and a <= 5;
```

Of course, given your constrains, `a` cannot be 0, so the `case` is superfluous.

If you just want all the rows but the calculation for certain values of `a`, simplify to:

```
select a, b, c, d,
       (case when a >= 2 and a <= 5 then b/a end) as e
from table;
```

Comment: That second query is not equivalent (`when a >= 2 and a <= 5 then b`).  And it will divide by zero.